# Sharepoint 2013 REST API issue - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, workflow-tasks-list, postman

I am trying to update a `Tasks` list item via REST and sending the following body to SharePoint API via POSTMAN tool:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
    },
    "Status": "Approved",
    "WorkflowOutcome": "Completed",
    "PercentComplete": 1

}
```

[image]

But I only receive the following error, I tried multiple combinations. I tried even updating only `Title`, but always the same error response. Any clue what is the issue here?

[image]

**NOTE** : I am able to GET the list item :
[image]

Comment: Are you able to get the list items in postman? first check it: `siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Name')/items`

Comment: Yes i am able to get the list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that "Completed" is a valid value for "WorkflowOutcome", you have to set it to "Approved".  It has been a couple of years since I wrote this, but I performed a similar REST call on an old project that programmatically completes a workflow task using the following:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.TasksListItem"
    },
    "Status": "Approved",
    "FormData": "Completed",
    "WorkflowOutcome": "Approved",
    "Completed": true,
    "PercentComplete": 1

}
```

Comment: I had infact tried with WorkflowOutcome as "Approved" and just for testing purpose i was changing those values. With value as "Approved" also it didnt work. I think updating`FormData` and `Completed` did the trick here. Thank you.

Comment: That makes sense, like I said, it has been at least a couple of years, but I recall having to do a lot of trial and error to get it right.

Comment: do you know how to update the comments? I am unable to find the field in the task list where the comment is saved. Hence unable to GET or POST Approval Comments.